# How to include an image inside another image in PHP?

Tags: php, gd

How to include an image inside another image in PHP? I want to do it like in twitterbackgrounds.com personalized backgroud. there is one main image and we can upload four personal images after that it will show as watermark of the main image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to draw an image over another image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405871/php-how-to-draw-an-image-over-another-image)

Comment: Make sure you have GD enabled on your server -- you can find this out using phpinfo(); -- then there is a simple way to merge images using php GD library. You'll get info about it on php.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several possibilies to do that. The one that pops into my mind is to use a php page where you can upload all files needed for this. After submission you can use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to create the new image with watermarks and display it on another webpage or store it to a database.

[Here is a good tutorial on how to use imagemagick to create the watermarks in another image](http://www.selonen.org/arto/netbsd/watermarks.html).

you may use imagemagick as commandline command from php or use it as a server application on an own server

Answer (score 2):

I never used GD by myself, but look at the [example in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php), wich is about "Using imagecopymerge() to create a translucent watermark".

Answer (score 1):

[phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) has a watermark feature, if you're looking for something full-featured and ready-made..