# put one image on the other one

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP: How to draw an image over another image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405871/php-how-to-draw-an-image-over-another-image)
>   [How to include an image inside another image in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003702/how-to-include-an-image-inside-another-image-in-php)

Hello
How can I put one image on the other one with php?
Thank`s for help

Comment: Yeah, why don't people search for answers before asking a question? This is such a basic thing that's already been asked & answered numerous times (not only here on SO, a simple Google search returns LOTS of information).

Answer (score 0):

Same as [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)(example 1) except the destination image(which is blank) will be your original image.