# Place and image over another image - Javascript & PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image-processing, imagemagick

Simple website that will have an image in the background. Always fixed image.

Then the user will upload an image which will be overlay with the background image. Then user can resize the image they uploaded and then rotate, resize etc to suit the background.

Finally once uploaded image is loaded correctly they save. This has be using javascript and php. User can do all the rotating, zooming of their uploaded image and save file in php to send new file to user.

Question is how to create the system that accepts and image and allows user to rotate and resize their images to fit the background on the browser. Any recommended javascript plugin that can allow rotation and resizing image so that user can fit it with the background image?

Please see attachment explaining in detail 
[image]

Comment: Okay and good illustrations, but what is your question?

Comment: Question is how to create the system that accepts and image and allows user to rotate and resize their images to fit the background on the browser.

Comment: Placing an image over another is simple CSS absolute positioning. Resizing/rotating can be done with various CSS transforms, though doing it in a Canvas object would be far easier. Either way, you'd need a fairly recent version browser, as css rotation is a recent addition to the spec.

Answer (score 1):

use CSS rotation and absolute positioning.

Comment: You should use PHP's graphic libraries (GD). here's your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405871/php-how-to-draw-an-image-over-another-image