# How to draw a png image in php?

Tags: php

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(538,616);

$black = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);

imagefill($image,0,0,$black);
```

I have already draw a black image i want draw a file suppose 3.png on it ..
How to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to draw an image over another image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405871/php-how-to-draw-an-image-over-another-image)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to load an image you want to draw and then use [`imagecopy()`](http://www.php.net/imagecopy) to draw it:

```
// the part you already have; creates 538x616 px black image
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(538,616);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
imagefill($image,0,0,$black);

// load image from file and draw it onto black image;
// for loading PNG, use imagecreatefrompng()
$overlayImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('macro_photo_1.jpg');
imagecopy($image, $overlayImage, 10, 10, 0, 0, imagesx($overlayImage), imagesy($overlayImage));

// send image to the browser    
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
exit;
```

I would also advise to go through the list of [GD and Image functions](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) to see what (and how) can be done with images in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
imagepng($image);
```

And if you haven't already you need:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

Before you call imagepng to let the browser know it's looking at an image not an HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Saroj, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php and from same page, here is the example snippet

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

HTH!